# Fragmentでreplaceしてもレイアウトが重なる

Tags: android, fragment

現在`Fragment`を使ってアプリを作っているのですが、`Fragment`の使い方がイマイチ分かっていません。最初は`layout.xml`で指定した`Fragment`に`add`や`replace`をしていたのですが、それではうまく機能しないということが分かったので、以下のコードのようにしてみたのですが、ボタンを押したときに`FragmentA`のレイアウトと`FragmentB`のレイアウトが重なってしまいます。色々調べてみても`Fragment`の使い方がイマイチ分からず困っています。どうすれば`Fragment`を使ってレイアウトを切り替えることができるでしょうか？すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentA());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn); {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, new FragmentB());
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ボタンクリック時、`add`を呼んでいるので重なるのは当然のように思えます。`replace`が正しいです。

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn); {
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        // addを呼んでいるので、重なる
        transaction.add(R.id.container, new FragmentB());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、確かにreplaceしなければならないですね。うっかりしてました。おかげで問題が解決できました。ありがとうございました。